# Google Search Console indexing non existent pages for a Create React App website with react-helmet-async hosted on Netlify

Tags: google-search-console, react-js, netlify

Google is showing non-existing pages when I search for my website (hosted on `Netlify`)

it looks like this: `https://*********.com.tr/Achlamydeae1901520.html` or `https://*********.com.tr/Cumar1152083.html` (These pages Does not exist and the user will get redirected to the 404 custom page I created).

my `sitemap.txt` looks like this  :

```
https://*********.com.tr/
https://*********.com.tr/about
https://*********.com.tr/companies
https://*********.com.tr/team
https://*********.com.tr/activities
https://*********.com.tr/contact
```

my `_redirects` file looks like this :

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

my `robots.txt` file looks like this :

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /nogooglebot/

User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: https://*********.com.tr/sitemap.txt
```

my meta in `react-helmet-async` looks like this  :

```
<Helmet>
     <title>website title</title>
              <meta
                name="description"
                content="This is a desciption"
              />
              <meta
                name="keywords"
                content="this is the website keywords"
              />
             
    
              <link rel="canonical" href="/" />
</Helmet>
```

my `React router v6` looks like this :

```
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
          <Route path="companies" element={<OurCompanies />} />
          <Route path="team" element={<OurTeam />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<AboutUs />} />
          <Route path="activities" element={<Activities />} />
          <Route path="news" element={<ComingSoon />} />

          <Route path="*" element={<Error404 />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

EDIT : In Google Search Console I found that there are more than 3k URLs like the two I have mentioned above under the `Coverage` category This is a screenshot to demonstrate

[image]

Comment: Is your web server configured to serve your react application for every URL regardless of whether or not React has a valid routing for that URL?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I did not configure anything in netlify 
I just uploaded my site output folder (build) folder ,
I used this guide https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-react-router-based-app-to-netlify/

Comment: Is there a .htaccess file in your build directory that you uploaded?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No there is not, I have _redirects file in my public directory which is required in order to react-router redirection to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has been solved thanks to the awesome people at Google Search Help.

[This answer from there](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/161724782?hl=en&msgid=161732879) worked for me:

> Looks like you're a purely client side rendered site here, so the page returns a 200 status. (You can't change a status code client side)
>
> So despite the page saying 404, it's really a 200.
>
> The two options for a client side routed site are:
>
> - Add a noindex  tag
> - Or do a JavaScript redirect to a page outside the app, that actually returns a 404
>
> Both will work about the same, and result in the same outcome (these URLs being dropped from the index) so really pick the easiest to implement.